# java inability to notify() thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

Currently I am trying to build a snake game as my first project in java, and am using threads. I want to have an object wait when it reaches the border of the screen, and then be notified when a key input comes in to continue moving another direction. 
At the bottom I invoke the notify() function yet nothing happens, and the thread continues to be in a wait() state. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
package com.foreverblu.snake;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class snakeobject extends JPanel{
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int z = 0;
int a = 0;
Thread animationThread;
Thread notifyThread;
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponents(g);
    this.setBackground(Color.black);
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.fill3DRect(x, y, 30, 30, true);



}
public void keepGoing() {
     animationThread = new Thread(create);
     notifyThread = new Thread(create2);
}
Runnable create = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        synchronized(this) {
        while(z>=0 || z<=3) {
            if(z==2 && y>0) {
            y-=30;
            repaint();
            try{Thread.sleep(500);} catch (Exception ex) {}
            }else if(z==1 && y<=450) {
                y+=30;
                repaint();
                try {Thread.sleep(500);} catch (Exception ex) {}
            }else if(z==0 && x<=450) {
                x+=30;
                repaint();
                try{Thread.sleep(500);} catch (Exception ex) {}
            }else if(z==3 && x>0) {
                x-=30;
                repaint();
                try{Thread.sleep(500);} catch (Exception ex) {}
            }else{
                notifyThread.notify();
            }
        }
        }

    }
};
Runnable create2 = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        synchronized(this) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                animationThread.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        do{try{Thread.sleep(500);} catch (Exception ex) {}
        continue;
        }while(a==0);
        if(a==1) {
        System.out.println("Notified");

        a=0;
        animationThread.notifyAll();
        }
    }
    }

};

}
```

The other class:
    package com.foreverblu.snake;

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class snakeframe extends JFrame{
int z = 0;
snakeobject swag = new snakeobject();
public snakeframe() {
    super("The Great Title");
    swag.keepGoing();
    swag.notifyThread.start();
    swag.animationThread.start();
    addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if(swag.animationThread.getState()==Thread.State.WAITING) {
                    swag.a=1;
                    System.out.println("Swag");

            }
            if(swag.animationThread.getState()==Thread.State.RUNNABLE) {
                System.out.println("RUNNABLE");
            }
            if(e.getExtendedKeyCode()==e.VK_DOWN) {
                swag.z=1;

            }else if(e.getExtendedKeyCode()==e.VK_UP) {
                swag.z=2;
            }else if(e.getExtendedKeyCode()==e.VK_LEFT) {
                swag.z=3;
            }else if(e.getExtendedKeyCode()==e.VK_RIGHT) {
                swag.z=0;
            }
        }

    });
    add(swag);
}
}
```

Comment: Well, for one you're using wait/notify incorrectly. Synchronizing on one monitor but notifying another. You should be getting exceptions if any of the relevant code is executed. You don't really need to use extra threads either since the EDT and main thread would suffice.

Comment: You mention doing this as your first Java project. I suggest you do away with threads and go for more basic designs first. Multi-threading is not something you should begin with.

Answer (score 0):

> Currently I am trying to build a snake game as my first project in java, and am using threads.

You're trying to learn too many things at the same time;

- The Java language,
- Java standard libraries,
- Swing, and how to design desktop GUI applications,
- How threads work, and how to use them to your advantage.

Slow down. Take them one at a time.

---

> I want to have an object wait when it reaches the border of the screen, and then be notified when a key input comes in...

That doesn't sound like a thread.  Dedicating a thread to each moving object in your game is a very limiting design choice, and having a thread that waits for different things depending on its state sounds like a bad design (IMO).  For example, I would not code a thread that waits on the real-time clock (i.e., calls `sleep()`) when the snake is moving, and then waits for a key press when in some other state.

There already is a thread that waits for key presses:  It's called the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT), and it is automatically created for you in any Swing program.  And, if you want to wait on the clock (e.g., to animate an object in a game), you're probably better off using a Swing `Timer` for that.

---

You should be aware that *most* Swing methods (e.g., `repaint()`) may *only* be called from within the EDT.  There are only a very few, such as `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` that may be called from other threads.

---

The `o.wait()`, `o.notify()` and `o.notifyAll()` methods are low-level primitives that are meant to be used in a very specific pattern, to implement higher-level synchronization classess.  The Java standard library already defines a number of useful synchronization classes in the `java.util.concurrent` package.  Any time you think you want to use wait/notify, you should first check whether there's something in `java.util.concurrent` that would save you some effort.

If you *must* use wait/notify, then you should read Oracle's "Guarded Blocks" tutorial, and use it the way it was meant to be used:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html